# "xinput set-prop" worked in 17.04 but results in error in 17.10

Tags: xorg, mouse, xinput, mouse-pointer

I was able to set a property for my Mouse via xinput (*libinput Accel Speed Default (287):  0.000000*) in my Ubuntu 17.04. After upgrading to 17.10 the following command now fails:

```
dan4o@dan4o-desktop:~$ sudo xinput set-prop 9 287 -0.9
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
Serial number of failed request:  19
Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

I don't see anything related to the call in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/Xorg.0.log. /var/log/auth.log did contain info about opening and closing session for user root and the xinput command.

Would appreciate greatly any help on what is causing the error as well as suggestions for another way to tweak options and properties for my mouse. Thanks in advance!

Output for xdg session:

```
dan4o@dan4o-desktop:~$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11
```

Not sure if this also helps, but here is xorg version

```
dan4o@dan4o-desktop:~$ apt-cache show xserver-xorg | grep Version
Version: 1:7.7+19ubuntu3
```

Comment: Please execute the command `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and include the output in your question

Comment: I have added the command output along with xorg version to the question.

Comment: Is your mouse still device 9?  You can verify this with `xinput --list`

Comment: yeah it is 9, it was 9 even in the 17.04 version. It sometimes does change to 8 if i plug a couple of usbs in. Using wrong device number would result in another error.  Device 9 is my mouse and 287 can be found as property in the otput of `xinput list-props 9`

Comment: I note on my mouse, the *accell speed default* is property 277 - can you check you mouse via `xinput list-props 9`?

Comment: K - I think we're going to have to see if someone with more experience than I looks at this question

Comment: Well there is Acceleration Spped Default (287) and Acceleration Speed (286). I can actually set the 286 property... it kind of does what i wanted it to do - the equivalent of the enhance pointer precision option  in Windows. Thanks for helping me!